# Find the inverse of the function $r(x)=1-2f(3-4x)$ in terms of $f^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

I have absolutely no idea to inverse functions containing different functions. Apparently this is a one-to-one function with inverse $f^{-1}$ and I'm asked to calculate the inverses of the given functions in terms of $f^{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=r^{-1}(x)$

Then $r(y)=x$

So $1-2f(3-4y)=x$

Rearrange to make $y$ the subject...

$1-x=2f(3-4y)$

$\frac{1-x}2=f(3-4y)$

$f^{-1} \left (\frac{1-x}2 \right )=3-4y$

$4y=3-f^{-1} \left (\frac{1-x}2 \right )$

$y=\frac 34- \frac 14 f^{-1} \left (\frac{1-x}2 \right )$

$r^{-1}(x)=\frac 34- \frac 14 f^{-1} \left (\frac{1-x}2 \right )$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x)=3-4x$ and $h(x)=1-2x$

Note that both $g$ and $h$ are one to one and invertible over the real numbers.

Note further that $r(x)= (h\circ f\circ g)(x)$

By properties of composition of invertible functions, $r^{-1}=(h\circ f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}$

We can find $h^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ and simplify leaving an expression for $r^{-1}$ that depends only on $x$ and $f^{-1}$

Comment: I think your "By properties of composition of invertible functions..." Part is what is being asked by op: "how does one get that?".

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD How does one know that $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$?  It is generally proven as an exercise in an early course on set theory or it is often stated as a property in a pre-calculus course.  If asking how does one continue the simplifications, the OP implies that he would know how to find the inverse of a function like $h(x)=1-2x$  (it is $h^{-1}(x)=\frac{1-x}{2}$) and how to compose functions should also be understood at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!